# Can not access my user controls' properties

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a user control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" ClassName="WebUserControl" %>
<script runat="server">
public string name { get; set; }
</script>
```

Then on a page I have

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/my_control.ascx" TagName="MyControl" TagPrefix="Me"%>
<Me:MyControl runat="server" ID="myControl1" />
```

and I can see the property if I do

```
<Me:MyControl runat="server" ID="myControl1" name="Hello World"/>
```

However, if from my code behind, or code tags I try

```
myControl1.name
```

I get nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Okay so what I did was scrap my control, and re-write the whole thing. Then I added it to my page via drag and drop. Now it works. I have no idea why.

Comment: Which is not a good outcome, as you haven't learned anything. Can you post the markup and code-behind for your new usercontrol AND your page please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `using` directive in your page. Add a `using {your.control.namespace}` statement.

Comment: intellisense isnt showing me any namespaces that my control would be in. To be clear I am able to get the control just fine from my codebehind, it just wont give me any of its public properties that I have created.

Comment: Your usercontrol definitely *is* in a namespace. Instead of declaring the server-side code in a <script runat="server">, try re-creating the usercontrol and using a code behind instead. That way you will be able to identify the namespace it is in.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

This is related to control state:

```
   public string name
   {
       get
          {
             object obj = ViewState["name"];
              return (obj == null) ? "" : obj.ToString();
           }
        set
        {
             ViewState["name"] = value;
         }
    }
```

You may find addtional information here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.loadcontrolstate(v=vs.100).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1whwt1k7(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I dont quite understand what im supposed to do with that override. Also the expanded version of name you gave me still does not yet work.

Comment: @SteveWellens I agree that it may work without it but in order to keep the object state some good practices  needs to be followed.

Comment: This is a good practice if you want to persist the 'name' property between posts, but it doesn't explain his problem, which is that he has no intellisense for his control instance in a page that uses the control.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine.  Did you drag and drop the control onto a **form**?

Comment: Nope this isnt in my toolbox. I simply put the register directive at the top of my page and then intellisense poped up as i began typing <My:....>. To be clear everything works expect I cant get its properties from my code behind.

Comment: It doesn't have to be in the toolbox.  You can drag and drop it from the Solution/Project explorer.

Comment: I just did a drag and drop, and I tried to access "name" from my codebhind by doing the same thing as i tried above but had no luck. It doesnt make sense that on my aspx page intellisense sees "name" when I type it, but if I try to access that property from codebehind, its no good.

Comment: Try doing a build.  The intellisense for markup is different than the intellisense for code.  Sometimes the code needs to be compiled before intellisense works...in my experience.